# How do I do if statement arithmetic in bash?

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to do something like this:

```
if [ $1 % 4 == 0 ]; then
...
```

But this does not work.

What do I need to do instead?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

```
read n
if ! ((n % 4)); then
    echo "$n divisible by 4."
fi
```

The `(( ))` operator evaluates expressions as C arithmetic, and has a boolean return.

Hence, `(( 0 ))` is false, and `(( 1 ))` is true. [1]

The `$(( ))` operator also expands C arithmetic expressions, but instead of returning true/false, it returns the value instead. Because of this you can test the output if `$(( ))` in this fashion: [2]

```
[[ $(( n % 4 )) == 0 ]]
```

But this is tantamount to: `if (function() == false)`. Thus the simpler and more idiomatic test is:

```
! (( n % 4 ))
```

[1]: Modern bash handles numbers up to your machine's `intmax_t` size.

[2]: Note that you can drop `$` inside of `(( ))`, because it dereferences variables within.

Comment: For the first example, might I suggest that: `! ((n % 4))` would read better as `(( n % 4 == 0 ))`?

Comment: There is a subtle point to mention to non C programmers. A successful return value of a function is ZERO. A non zero return value indicates an error (as per Unix, Linux). However, a zero value in an if statement test expression in C, equates to the Boolean false, and non zero to a Boolean true; lest any reader confuses the two...which actually IS confusing...I am not just adding a comment for point scoring,,,when I saw the explanation I was like "...wait a minute, but a successful return code is ZERO!"...

Comment: Note that it **won't** yield the same result if the exclamation `!` is glued to the `(`, i.e., `!((...)`

Answer (score 17):

Single brackets (`[..]`) don't work for some tests. Try with double brackets (`[[...]]`) and enclose the mod in `((..))` to evaluate the `%` operator properly:

```
if [[ $(( $1 % 4 )) == 0 ]]; then
```

More details are in *[7.2. More advanced if usage](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html)*.

Comment: "Contrary to [, [[ prevents word splitting of variable values. So, if VAR="var with spaces", you do not need to double quote $VAR in a test - eventhough using quotes remains a good habit. Also, [[ prevents pathname expansion, so literal strings with wildcards do not try to expand to filenames. Using [[, == and != interpret strings to the right as shell glob patterns to be matched against the value to the left, for instance: [[ "value" == val* ]]." -- good stuff

Answer (score 15):

```
a=4
if [ $(( $a % 4 )) -eq 0 ]; then                                
     echo "I'm here"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you:

```
((a%4==0)) && echo "$a is divisible by 4" || echo "$a is not divisible by 4"
```

or more succinctly:

```
((a%4)) && echo "$a is not divisible by 4" || echo "$a is divisible by 4"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something a bit more portable - for example, something that works in `sh` as well as in `bash` - use

```sh
if [ $(echo "$1 % 4" | bc) -eq 0 ]; then
...
```

An example

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#@file: trymod4.bash

if [ $(echo "$1 % 4" | bc) -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "$1 is evenly divisible by 4"
else
  echo "$1 is NOT evenly divisible by 4"
fi
```

```sh
$ chmod +x trymod4.bash
$ ./trymod4.bash 224
224 is evenly divisible by 4
$ ./trymod4.bash 223
223 is NOT evenly divisible by 4
```

I put this in, because you used the single `[ ... ]` conditional, which I usually associate with `sh`-compatible programs.

---

Check that this works in `sh`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#@file: trymod4.sh

if [ $(echo "$1 % 4" | bc) -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "$1 is evenly divisible by 4"
else
  echo "$1 is NOT evenly divisible by 4"
fi
```

```sh
$ chmod +x trymod4.sh
$ ./trymod4.sh 144
144 is evenly divisible by 4
$ ./trymod4.sh 19
19 is NOT evenly divisible by 4
```

All right, it works with `sh`.

Note the "theoretical" (but not always implemented as such) differences between `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]` from [this site](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031#line-24) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20200207065502/http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031#line-24)).