# how to compare current time with two different times along with dayofweek in unix shell script?

Tags: shell, date, unix, awk, sed

How to compare two timestamps along with another condition.
Please find below code as an trial for the work around.

```
d=$(date +%Y%m%d)          #Today
d1=$(date +%b" "%d)        #Centre1 col 1 & 2 (MON DD)
ct=$(date +'%H%M%S')       #Current Time (HHMM)
t01='013000'
t02='033000'
t03='053000'
t04='073000'


find . -mtime 0 -iname "RBDEXT*.csv" -ls | awk '{printf("%-5s%s\t%-40s%s\t%s\t\n", $8,$9,$11,$10,$7)}' > rbdextmp1.txt


rbdextCO=$(wc -l rbdextmp1.txt | awk '{print $1}')
rbdextIN=$(cat rbdextmp1.txt | grep "inprogress" | wc -l)

touch centre.txt

if [[ [ "$rbdextIN" -eq 0 ] &&
 [ [ "$ct" -gt "$t01" ] && [ "$ct" -lt "$t02" ] && [ "$rbdextCO" -eq 1 ]  ||
   [ "$ct" -gt "$t02" ] && [ "$ct" -lt "$t03" ] && [ "$rbdextCO" -eq 2 ]  ||
   [ "$ct" -gt "$t03" ] && [ "$ct" -lt "$t04" ] && [ "$rbdextCO" -eq 3 ] ]
 ]]

then
echo "$d1 RBDEXT.$d.csv($rbdextCO) OK" >> centre.txt
elif [ "$rbdextIN" -ge 1 ]
then
echo "$d1 RBDEXT.$d.csv($rbdextCO) OKBUT" >> centre.txt
else
echo "$d1 RBDEXT.$d.csv($rbdextCO) NOK" >> centre.txt
fi
```

Could you please help me on this please, Thanks a lot !

Comment: Instead of "it's not working for me", tell us what it does, that you don't expect. 
Also, where's the closing `fi`?

Comment: @EdMorton, Hello Sir, I updated the question as per the requirement. Kindly update.

Comment: @EdMorton, Sir, I have updated the question and I guess It may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
currenttime=$(date +'%H%M%S')
dayofweek=$(date +'%u')

time1='013000'
time2='033000'
time3='053000'
time4='073000'

count=$(wc -l < xxx.txt)

if (( (dayofweek == 1) &&
      ( ( (currenttime > time1) && (currenttime < time2) && (count == 1) ) ||
        ( (currenttime > time2) && (currenttime < time3) && (count == 2) ) ||
        ( (currenttime > time3) && (currenttime < time4) && (count == 3) ) )
   ))
then
    color="GREEN"
else
    color="RED"
fi

printf 'GP_GLOBAL_FEED(%s)  %s\n' "$count" "$color" |
mailx -s "$color" abcd@mail.com
```

Comment: You're welcome. I can't help you debug any errors if you don't tell me exactly what they are though.

Comment: ,Sir, Thank you so much for the inputs, I am getting the else part output with below message and I pasted the whole code in the asked question.

./t.ksh[38]: rbdextIN: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: The script you posted that's producing a syntax error isn't the same as the script I posted. For example, you've changed the `((` ... `))` arithmetic op delimiters to nested single brackets `(<space>( .. )<space>)`. Put it back to the style/syntax I gave you then run it to make sure it works. Now make 1 change and run it again - if you get an error then that change introduced the error. Repeat until you identify which change you made that caused the error.

Comment: Also get rid of the UUOCs (`cat file | cmd` -> `cmd file`, google it), always double quote all your shell variables unless you have a specific purpose in mind by not doing so (google it), don't parse the output of ls (google it), change `rbdextCO=$(wc -l rbdextmp1.txt | awk '{print $1}')` back to `rbdextCO=$(wc -l < rbdextmp1.txt)`, and set a variable and print once like I did rather than printing the same string with 1 small change in multiple places.

Comment: Note in particular that `(<space>(...)<space>)` is very different from `((...))`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8304195/1745001, but please do clean up all that other stuff too.

Comment: You're welcome. Please restore your question to what it was. This site isn't just a place to ask questions, it's a repository where people with similar questions can look up those questions and find the associated answers.

Comment: Question is restored ! Thank You for your time

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you build up to this slowly.

Start with:

```
if [ "2" -gt "1" ]
then
   echo "Green"
else
   echo "Red"
fi
```

... check that it works. **Then** add a second clause using `&&`, resolve any syntax problems, make sure it works. **Then** replace your hard-coded values with variables. **Then** populate the variables with output from `date`. Check that it still works after each step. You'll get there.

Bonus tip -- backticks for command substitution have been frowned upon for some time, because it's easy to make mistakes. Use `currentTime=$(date +%H%M%S)` instead.