# How to use if then in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

We have a text file with 4 lines and a different number of words and i want to count the words per line and see if the number is even or odd but the result keeps saying

```
./oddwords.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./oddwords.sh: line 14: `  if[ n % 2 == 0 ]; then'
```

This is what ive done so far

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ] ; then
{
  echo "Wrong number of arguments!"
  exit 1
}
fi



while read line ; do
n= echo "$(echo $line | wc -w)"
if[ n % 2 == 0 ]; then
  echo "Is even"
 else
  echo "Is odd"
fi

done < $1
```

Comment: paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation. If then is not the only issue you have.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304005/how-do-i-do-if-statement-arithmetic-in-bash
Is this the answer?

Comment: @kyakya i figured out the problem thanks to Jetchisel for pointing out quite the helping website. I had forgotten a space along with some other mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using double brackets like
`if [[ n % 2 == 0 ]]; then`
and making the numbers variables at the top instead of just saying 2

```
a=2
b=1
```

at the beginning then referencing them later in the if statement like
`if [[ $a%2 == 0 ]]; then`

if you still have issues try
 `if [[ $a%2 -eq 0 ]]; then`

Here are a couple sites i find useful for checking bash when I get stuck on something as well.

https://www.shellcheck.net/

https://explainshell.com/